# How to write a recipe to get the real email sender

Tags: email, procmail, mime-mail

I am trying to send email back to the sender using `sendmail -oi -t`, but somehow it extracted MTA, how to write the receipt to get the real sender since the email return-path and first From in the email header is MTA, not the real sender? So sendmail can deliver email back to: Sender: +xxxxxxxxxx@tmomail.net
or From: +xxxxxxxxxx@tmomail.net

Here is the procmail.log and email received:

```
...
procmail: Matched "+1xxxxxxxxxx@tmomail.net"
procmail: Match on "^Sender: \/.+"
procmail: Assigning "LASTFOLDER= (/usr/bin/formail -rA"Precedence: junk" \
-A"X-Loop:addr@mydomain.com" \
-I"To: $MATCH"; \
echo "$result"; \
) | /usr/sbin/sendmail -oi -t"
procmail: Assigning "PATH=/home/r/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin"
procmail: Unable to treat as directory "/var/mail/new"
procmail: Skipped "/var/mail"
procmail: Assigning "LASTFOLDER=/var/mail/r"
procmail: Executing " (/usr/bin/formail -rA"Precedence: junk" \
-A"X-Loop:addr2mydomain.com" \
-I"To: $MATCH"; \
echo "$result"; \
) | /usr/sbin/sendmail -oi -t"
procmail: Opening "/var/mail/r"
procmail: Acquiring kernel-lock
procmail: Notified comsat: "r@884017:/var/mail/r"
From btv1==909280b6006==+1xxxxxxxxxx/TYPE=PLMN@tmomail.net  Mon Apr 11  17:09:24 2016
Folder: /var/mail/r
```

Here is the email header:

```
From btv1==9062f44d095==+xxxxxxxxxx/TYPE=PLMN@tmomail.net  Fri Apr  8 00:19:01 2016
Return-Path: <btv1==9062f44d095==+xxxxxxxxxx/TYPE=PLMN@tmomail.net>
X-Original-To: recipient@mydomain.com
Delivered-To: recipient@mydomain.com
Received: from ch3p-tmo-mm3-sfw004.syniverse.com (chi-tmo-mm3.syniverse.com   [x.x.x.x])
    by mail.mydomain.com (Postfix) with ESMTP id 7D444222D0
    for <recipient@mydomain.com>; Fri,  8 Apr 2016 00:19:01 +0000 (UTC)
Received: from tmobile.net ([10.166.3.161]) by ch3p-tmo-mm3-      sfw004.syniverse.com with ESMTP id RuIW8dEKbs9H2Iyg for <r@mr4.biz>; Fri, 08 Apr   2016 00:18:58 +0000 (GMT)
To: recipient@mydomain.com
From: +xxxxxxxxxx@tmomail.net
Content-Type: multipart/related;Type="text/html";boundary="-boundaryRMS123"
Date: Fri, 8 Apr 2016 00:18:58 GMT
Message-ID: 20160308001858639184@mavenir.com
Sender: +xxxxxxxxxx@tmomail.net
User-Agent: iPhoneOS/9.2.1 (13D15)
X-Virus-Scanned: by bsmtpd at syniverse.com
```

Here is the last part of recipe:

```
:0hc
* !^X-Loop:old@domain.com
* ^Sender: \/.+
| (/usr/bin/formail -rA"Precedence: junk" \
                     -A"X-Loop:addr@mydomain.com" ; \
   echo "$result"; \
) | /usr/sbin/sendmail -oi -t
```

Answer (score 1):

You are instructing `formail` to generate a reply and it will faithfully attempt to do so.  By default, the `-r` option tries to select the best one out of a priority list of headers<sup>1</sup>; if the message has a `Reply-To:` header (but no `Resent-From:`, and no `Resent-Reply-To:`, etc), it will generate a reply to that.

With `-rt`, you get RFC-compliant but somewhat less pragmatic behavior, but it doesn't really help here.

Anyway, if you know exactly which header you want to reply to, just use that.

```
:0hc
* ! ^X-Loop:old@domain\.com
* ^Sender: \/.+
| ( formail -rA"Precedence: junk" \
             -A"X-Loop:r@mydomain.com" \
             -I"To: $MATCH"; \
    echo "$result"; \
  ) | /usr/sbin/sendmail -oi -t
```

This uses `formail -r` in order to get correct `In-reply-to:` and `References:` headers (as well as any previous `X-Loop:`) but overwrites the generated `To:` header with the one we captured from the `Sender:` header.

The `\/` token in a Procmail regular expression causes anything after it to be captured into the variable `MATCH`.  We use this to grab the value of the `Sender:` header from the incoming message.

---

1. http://www.iki.fi/era/procmail/formail.html -- this is from an older version, but this code hasn't changed in a loooooong time.

Comment: I added the line * ^Sender: \/.+ and -I"To: $MATCH"; \, it says: procmail: Executing " (/usr/bin/formail -rA"Precedence: junk" \
  -A"X-Loop:addr@mydomain.com" ; \
  -I"To: $MATCH"; \ "
/bin/sh: 3: Syntax error: end of file unexpected (expecting ")")

Comment: What  line * ^Sender: \/.+ does and the $MATCH is the sender? Why it's inside the double quote?

Comment: The `\/` token in a Procmail regular expression causes anything after it to be captured into the variable `MATCH`.  We generally put double quotes around all variables unless we specifically require the shell to perform token splitting and wildcard expansion on the value; see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-variable

Comment: The error message looks like maybe you have whitespace after one of the backslashes.  They need to be the very last thing on the line; their purpose is to escape the following newline.  Also, the semicolon after `-A"XLoop:..."` needs to be removed.

Comment: Thanks! it takes longer to email back, don't know why @tripleee

Comment: What takes longer, how exactly?